# IE8 .next() or closest() dosen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I try to debug a IE8 bug and I'm pretty stuck with it

```
$('.help-link').live('click', function (evt) {
var content = $(this).next('.help-content');
   if (!content.is(':visible')) {
       content.fadeIn(200);
   $(this).addClass('on');
    } else {
   content.fadeOut(150);
   $(this).removeClass('on');
   }
});
```

If you click on the link a div right under the link should fade in and fade out on the second click actually very simple. Works for all browsers just fine all but IE8. I also didn't find any solution to debug the script. The dev tool bar of the IE ignores my "console.log()"s. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: to get console.log working in ie8, you need to surround them in if(window.console) { ... } and have the page load WHILE the developer tools window is open

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML code, so that we can test the code...

Comment: Also, consider upgrading to IE9, which has superior dev tools. You will still be able to view pages in "compatibility mode".

Comment: A malformed code could generate some script issues on older browsers... have you previously validated your markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a ); at the end, not sure if it matters:

http://jsfiddle.net/BPCUL/

Comment: Thanks, but it was only a copy paste mistake the ); was in my original code

Which makes the thing even more strange since it works fine on jsfiddle.net

Comment: the JS fiddle i linked works perfectly for me in IE8. Perhaps there is something else causing the problem?

Comment: yep, It's a pretty complicated script I try to exclude all other scripts.

Comment: I would suggest building on a fiddle incrementally until you find which piece causes IE8 to explode, then you can isolate the actual problem and solve that :)

Comment: It was a css problem.     behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc); didn't work. Sorry for stealing your time and thx